# How to get timestamp for converted i18n date using momentjs

Tags: internationalization, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm using momentjs with timezone.

I've converted date to i18n using `moment.locale('pt');`

Now I want to get timestamp of the date. I get date value as converted i18n date, i.e. `Ago 14 2018 22:00`

I tried with `moment("Ago 14 2018 22:00").tz("Asia/Calcutta").unix()` => this is returing `NaN`

But this is working => `moment("Aug 14 2018 22:00").tz("Asia/Calcutta").unix()`

So how can I get timestamp of converted i18n date??

Here is fiddle of the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/10265/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first specify a `locale` as per [momentJS documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/).
You also need to make sure you have that locale and if not import it.

Here is an example:

```js
moment.locale('fr')
var date = moment("14 août 2018 10:37", "DD MMM YYYY hh:mm", "fr").format('LLL')
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, Aug in Portuguese is Ago

Comment: Added example. Hope this helps